# Passing method from parent to child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass method from controller - > parent directive - > child directive. I am calling this method from child controller by passing arguments. Its working in parent directive but I am not able to pass parameters from child directive. Below is the code :

http://jsfiddle.net/gurukashyap/e14ff06p/6/

From parent directive i get following response in console :
'Ctrl method 123'

From child directive :
Ctrl method undefined.

Any help appreciated.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <container data-method="foo(value)"/>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.directive('container', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        scope: {
            methodToCall: '&method'
        },
        template: "<div>" +
            "<button ng-click='finish()'>Parent directive</button><child data-method=\"methodToCall(val) \"></child>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.paragraphs = [];
            scope.pushText = function () {
                scope.paragraphs.push(scope.textToPush);
                scope.textToPush = "";
            }
            scope.finish = function () {
                scope.methodToCall({value: '123'});                                
            }
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            methodToCall : '&method'
        },
        template : '<button ng-click = "newMethod()">Child directive </button>',
        controller : function($scope) {
        $scope.newMethod = function () {
          console.log('Test child '+$scope);
            //debugger;
        $scope.methodToCall({val : 'Testchild'});
    }
     }
    }
});

myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.foo = function (textArray) {
        console.log('Ctrl method '+textArray)
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `container` template you are correctly invoking `methodToCall(val)` function on the scope, but you are only passing the local variable `val` to it (which you correctly, again, obtain from the `child` directive). You need, however, to pass a hash, like you did from the `child` directive.

So, change the part of the `container` template that includes `<child>` to:

```
<child data-method="methodToCall({value: val})"></child>
```

Perhaps, it would be more readable if you called an inner function and from there invoked the `"&"`-bound function:

```
scope: {
   methodToCall: '&method'
},
template: '<child data-method="innerMethodToCall(val)"></child>',
link: function(scope){
   scope.innerMethodToCall = function(val){
      scope.methodToCall({value: val});
   }
}
```

Your forked **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfrgLg8w/)**

Comment: thanks  that solved the issue. On similar lines if we call parent directive within child like recursively. Do we need to follow same procedure. <parent data-method="methodToCall({value: val})"></parent>

Comment: @Gurukashyap, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by recursively - do you mean that you could have depth N of inner `child` directives? - but, yes, you could something similar, except if it's truly recursive, you'd likely need `"methodToCall({val: val})"`, so as to not to redefine the local variable from `val` to `value`. But if all you are doing is bubbling up some data, there other ways to consider

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

You had a typo in the child directive where you were sending `val` instead of `value`.  The other issue is that you had created an isolate scope on the child directive.  This was breaking the scope inheritance chain.  Instead you need to either use no scope definition on the child directive **or** use `scope: true`.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2tw5mxf6/1/

discussion on `scope: {}` vs. `scope:true` - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7Rnd5RjdlCc

Comment: honestly, this seems like the wrong way to accomplish what you are doing.  While defining isolate scopes are great, in this case it doesn't seem like the right implementation.  If you expect to be traversing multiple scopes through the scope hierarchy, I'd recommend using the Angular event bus over this.  Then you can `$emit` the data which the controller can register via the `scope.$on` API. - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on